# Unable to access S3 bucket content: Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am using script to create an S3 bucket and uploading cloudformation templates to that bucket with same user credentials. 
But when trying to access the templates of that bucket using cloudformation, am getting access denied. I even tried adding the bucket policy and giving explicit access to that user but getting same "Access denied" error. Please suggest if am missing anything. Thank you.

Comment: The IAM role used by CF is not the same role you're using as an "user". Check the IAM policy associated with CF role and the bucket policy settings.

Comment: When you say "trying to access the templates of that bucket using cloudformation", what are you actually doing?

Comment: @oakad I have added `cloudformation.amazonaws.com` under trust relationships for that role but still it didn't work.

Comment: @jarmod I am uploading cloudformation templates to S3 bucket and then creating a  cloudformation stack using those templates.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to access the s3 bucket using cloud formation, you need to ensure that cloud formation should have proper permission to access S3 because this time you are not calling the S3 API but cloud formation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS CloudFormation via the management console, then CloudFormation will **use your *own* credentials** to retrieve the template from Amazon S3.

Therefore, the user that is using CloudFormation will require access to the object in Amazon S3.

If you believe that this has been correctly configured, please edit your Question to provide more details (eg the permissions granted to the user who is using CloudFormation).

Comment: I got it fixed. It was the nested template path issue but the S3 Access denied error was bit misleading which forced me to think about the access issues.